# One variable lookup according to single criteria in multiple columns and render occurrences of variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

1. I have 1 (only one) criteria in one sheet;
2. I want to lookup that criteria in a row in another sheet;
3. I want to find a certain word (only one word) in a set column of the row defined in point 2 above
4. I want to repeat point 3 above in 5 consecutive columns

Here below a formula that seemed logical to me, but that the spreadsheet did not really "like". Any suggestions?

```
=MATCH("Yes",(VLOOKUP($B$3,'Some_sheet'!$B$5:$ARU$221,65)):(VLOOKUP($B$3,'Some_sheet'!$B$5:$ARU$221,69)),1)
```

In other words: "I have a criteria in the current sheet that I want to find in another sheet ("Some_sheet"), and I want to lookup the word "Yes" that correspond to the row of the criteria from columns 65 to 69 (which correspond to columns BN to BR in this "Some_sheet")".

(I don't want to use VBA, if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX('Some_sheet'!$BN:$BR,MATCH($B$3,'Some_sheet'!$B:$B,0),0),"Yes")
```

What the formula does:

1. it matches the selection in cell `B3` to the column `B` of `Some_sheet` (`MATCH($B$3,'Some_sheet'!$B:$B,0)`)
2. it indexes columns `BN` to `BR` of `Some_sheet` (`INDEX('Some_sheet'!$BN:$BR,[…],0)`)
3. it counts the number of "`Yes`"'s in the line corresponding to step `1.`, from columns defined in step `2.` (`COUNTIF([…],"Yes")`)

Comment: To make is a good and complete answer, please describe what this code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup is the wrong formula, Use Index:

```
=MATCH("Yes",INDEX('Some_sheet'!$BN:$BR,MATCH($B$3,'Some_sheet'!$B:$B,0),0),0)
```

Comment: thanks for your input. However, the formula does not seem to work. Although I don't get an error anymore, I get the result 41 when it should be only 3. BN to BR (relative numbering as per VLOOKUP 65 to 69) are only 5 columns and they contain either "Yes", "No", or "".

Could you perhaps explain the formula?

Comment: Hello @Scott Craner. Thanks for the new input, however, the formula still does not work quite. This time the result that appears is **1**, when I expect **3**. When I change the word I want to count from `"Yes"` to `"No"`, it gives me **4**, when I expect **2**… It looks like `INDEX` 'does not understand' what it needs to do from columns `BN` to `BR`.